# Is passing around a GCC nested function valid? If not, are what alternatives are there for trampolining with state?

Tags: c, gcc, promise, nested-function

For a project I am working on I would like to use GCC nested functions because I would like to have a sort of lambda:

- I am not interested in supporting other compilers
- I don't want to access variables from the local context because I don't want to use trampolines

My platform is so far composed by a set of libraries and components and I would like to organise all the business logic on top of it using a combination of nested functions and promises.

My issue is that, as far I understand, the nested function dies within the function context and therefore if I access the function pointer after the function where it has been created returns I may end-up accessing mangled memory.

Is it correct? If yes, is there any alternative? (apart from using C++ :) )

From a very initial testing it looks like it's working when the nested functions are passed around but not sure if it's just because the memory wasn't being overwritten.

In addition, is there any GCC flag that can be used to trigger an error when GCC uses a trampoline for a nested function?

Thanks!

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html: **"If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose."**

Comment: @pmg Gotta love open source documentation :)

Comment: To answer the question, you should probably start be iterating through the program design a few times to see if it makes sense. Convoluted needs for strange function pointers and macro APIs most often originate from muddy design. I really can't come up with any use-case for nested functions at all, in any form of C program. That being said, you _could_ return a pointer to a `static` file scope function...

Comment: @pmg thanks, I totally missed that paragraph LOL

Comment: @rustyx I don't really think it's useful explaining the whys :) clearly you are not interested in them :)

Comment: Sorry @user2864740, I pointed it out in the title and tags but not in the body of the post. It's C not C++

Comment: @Lundin the reason for which I was thinking about nested functions is to have a "sort of" lambas to use with the promise pattern, having to pass a bunch of static function pointers would kill the purpose of it. I am thinking I can potentially have a pre-compilation step that will take care of converting all the lambdas defined using specific macros into static functions and then rely on file pointers but this, I can imagine, would kill the ability of GCC to optimise the code. Thanks for the hint anyway.

Comment: If the purpose is just to resolve various trivial stuff at compile-time, you can potentially do that without lambdas... it entirely depends on what the code should do.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right, the more I keep looking into this the more it looks really like a lot of effort for a not-well-defined benefit and I love the KISS principle so ... thanks for the hints and suggestions, I guess I will move forward with a more traditional approach and if I will get the need I will reconsider the idea during a second or third iteration.

Comment: I am aware that returning an inner function works if the inner function uses nothing from its parent scope, but I can't find that officially documented.

Comment: @rustyx: Because it's convenient and because the thing you're calling may not have a baton pointer argument. And best of all, it's easier to read the result.

Comment: @Joshua this was one of my tests together with checking if trampolines were being used and while I do think they would really help to improve the code readability I think that, probably, the better way is to rely on a pre-processor wrapper for 2 reasons: it would be portable and it would let the compiler to better optimise the code. But all of this work would make sense only if it would be actually paired with promises / futures otherwise very similar results can be achieved without this whole additional work.

Comment: I would just love to have lambdas, that would easily introduce the map/reduce patterns and would make way more easier to apply some nice principles commonly used with the functional programming that help a lot to structure the business logic in a sound way.